# Creating a rule for a file type

Tags: makefile

How can I create a rule in a makefile for a specific filetype so if I  write something like

```
result.txt: first.txt second.txt
```

in a makefile and it will concatenate prerequisites.

```
.txt:
     cat $? > $@
```

doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this seems to have helped, I am reposting it as an answer, with @eriktous' comment added in.

```
%.txt:
        cat $? >$@
```

If you don't want to process just the changed files, use `$^` instead of `$?`.